# How to evaluate this summation: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-progressions

How would I evaluate $\large\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i$? I'm having difficulty determining the first thing I should do.

Comment: Have you studied geometric series yet?

Comment: The first thing you might do is write down the first few cases, when $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$ and see if you find a pattern. This will at least hint at what the answer is, if not how to prove it.

Comment: @mixedmath Yes, the sequence keeps growing by a power of two until infinity.

Comment: @Mathmo123 No I haven't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT : Let S be the sum.
$$2S=\color{red}{2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-1}+2^{n}}+2^{n+1}$$
$$S=2^0+\color{red}{2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-1}+2^n}$$
Then, subtract the latter from the former.

Comment: What is $2S$ for? And why does it start with $2^1$ rather than $2^0$?

Comment: $2S=2\times S=2\times \sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i=2\times(2^0+2^1+\cdots+2^{n-1}+2^n)$ is for finding $S$. See the red parts are the same. And since $S$ starts with $2^0$, $2S$ starts with $2\times 2^0=2^1$.

Comment: Thanks. But how would I subtract both of them if I don't know all the terms in the sequences?

Comment: @David: Well, we know that the red parts are the same (do you agree?), so setting $A$ be the red part gives us $2S=A+2^{n+1}$ and $S=2^0+A$, right? So, all you need is to calculate $2S-S$, which is $S$.

Comment: So when I say the answer is $S$, what am I really saying?

Comment: Did you get $S=(A+2^{n+1})-(2^0+A)=2^{n+1}-1$? The answer is $2^{n+1}-1$. $S$ is just a name of your sum.

Comment: I understand now. So is this the process I should take when I want to solve a summation where the upper limit is an unknown variable?

Comment: Not really. I wrote this way because you said you don't know geometric series. Usually, your sum can be found by the formula Adi Dani wrote. see :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Answer (score 1):

There is a geometric series with ratio $q=2$ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i=\frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2}=2^{n+1}-1$$

Comment: Nope. The factor of $2$ is wrong. (The answer is an odd number.)

Comment: I will edit my answer!!!